# Failed carrier billing authorization with Google in-app billing

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I made an Android app that uses the google in-app billing.Most of the time this works just fine, but some users seem to fail the carrier billing authorization. In that case I get an email with the following text.

```
Google order # XXX has been cancelled because carrier billing authorization did 
not succeed for your buyer. The buyer was not charged.
```

I realize what that means and that the problem is not on my side, but I wonder what exactly happens in that case in the app. Does the order first go through and gets later canceled? What is the message flow in that case between google and my app?

Comment: @ SimonSays if you have solved this problem then please help me.

Comment: @atrivedi: sorry no, I still get this error every once in a while and have still no idea what exactly happens in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing bad in this message. Every payment transaction consists of two steps: authorization and capture. At authorization step Google Play tries to verify that payment instrument (in your case it is carrier account) is valid and there is enough funds there. If it succeed, then given amount of money are locked on that payment instrument for certain time. Next step is to capture or cancel this authorization. Capture means money will be claimed and moved to Google's account. By canceling no money transfer happens.

In your case the very first authorization step failed. You will normally see a *cancelled order* in the Google Wallet, but there will be *no cancelled payment* transaction in the bank records of user. If a payment transaction fails at authorization step, this is the same as there were no transaction at all.

What can you do to fix this? Nothing. It depends on what payment instrument is used and if there is enough founds there. If a user uses carrier account for payment with some limitation on it, there can be authorization fail, which is ok.

Is your application involved? Yes. It will be notified, that a payment has failed and you should not enable paid functions for that user. You don't need to do anything else. If user wants to, he or she will fix the issue (e.g top up his/her account) and try to purchase again.

Hope this helps.